# TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined&& Cannot read property &#39;location&#39; of undefine

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

Been trying to post a product with an image using AWS S3 (Multer and MulterS3). Each time I use the postman I receive "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" which is the line where I have the Image variable. What I'm I doing wrong?
here is my code.

## seller.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Product = require('../models/product');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const s3 = new aws.S3({accessKeyId:"XXXXX",secretAccessKey:"XXXXXX"})

const checkJWT = require('../middlewares/check-jwt');

/* image filter */
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(new Error('Invalid Mime Type, only JPEG and PNG'), false);
    }
  }

const upload = multer({
    fileFilter,
    storage: multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket:'XXXXX',
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now().toString())
      }
    })
  })

router.route('/products')
   .post([checkJWT, upload.single('product_picture')], (req, res, next) => {
   let product = new Product();
   product.owner = req.decoded.user._id;
   product.category = req.body.categoryId;
   product.title = req.body.title;
   product.price = req.body.price;
   product.description = req.body.description;
   product.image = req.file.location;
   product.save();
   res.json({
       success: true,
       message: 'Successfully Added the product'
   });
})
module.exports = router;
```

## product.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    reviews: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' } ],
    image: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

why i am not store image in s3. please help me.

Comment: When you send the post request via postman, do you set the header `Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: _italic_Yes @OTZ

Comment: Can you share how you are sending the request via postman in [code](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/)?

Comment: __italic_ @OTZ Solved issue. when i remove ```Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"``` from postman it working. Thanku @OTZ.